# How to change my eclipse console results line color.For every line different color using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to print eclipse console like this

System.out.println("He is a cricketer");`red color`
System.out.println("He is a dancer"); `yellow color`
System.out.println("He is a football player");`green color`
System.out.println("He is a volley player");`grey color`

Answer (score 3):

Console colors are controlled by Eclipse settings, but it can't print different colors in the same stream. For example, by default all `System.err` text is red and all `System.out` text is black (or white if you have the dark theme).

What you can do is install [ANSI Escape in Console plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console) for Eclipse, so the Eclipse console can interpret ANSI Escape codes. **Install it and restart Eclipse**.

Then you can do something like this, using ANSI Color Codes:

```java
public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "this text is red" + ANSI_RESET);
    System.out.println(ANSI_YELLOW + "this text is yellow" + ANSI_RESET);
    System.out.println(ANSI_CYAN + "this text is cyan" + ANSI_RESET);
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Output]

Here's a full [list of ANSI Color Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) if you need more colors.

Also, notice that `ANSI_RESET` makes text back to normal with all attributes off. Make sure you use it to reset the default color after you print colored text.